# How to automatically and programmatically Follow a Facebook page as a result of a user action?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

How to automatically and programmatically Follow a Facebook page as a result of a user action ? is this possible using Facebook GraphAPI ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not something like "follow" anymore since Graph API v2.0. What you probably mean is liking a Page, which is not possible via the API. It requires a user interaction.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes#Creating

> You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.